# How can I run a service that depends on xdg-desktop-autostart.target as root?

Tags: systemd, root, systemctl

Is it possible to run the `ExecStart` command in a systemd service with root privileges while depending on either `xdg-desktop-autostart.target` or `graphical-session.target`? If so, how?

For some context, I am trying to run the Sunshine game streaming server as a service on SteamOS. SteamOS's gaming mode uses Wayland. In order for Sunshine to work with Wayland, I must run the following command with root privileges:

`PULSE_SERVER=unix:$(pactl info | awk '/Server String/{print$3}') flatpak run dev.lizardbyte.sunshine`

I have put the command in a bash script located at `/home/deck/.local/bin/sunshine`. My systemd file (`sunshine.service`) is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sunshine is a self-hosted game stream host for Moonlight.
StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5
PartOf=graphical-session.target
Wants=xdg-desktop-autostart.target
After=xdg-desktop-autostart.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/deck/.local/bin/sunshine
ExecStop=flatpak kill dev.lizardbyte.sunshine
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=xdg-desktop-autostart.target
```

This service works as intended when starting placed in `/etc/systemd/service/` and started with `sudo systemctl start sunshine.service`. However, it fails when trying to enable the service with `sudo systemctl enable sunshine.service`. When enabling the service as a system service, it throws the following error:

`Unit /etc/systemd/system/sunshine.service is added as a dependency to a non-existent unit xdg-desktop-autostart.target.`

I understand why this is the case. The system isn't tied to a graphical session like users are. However, while I can enable it as a user service when I place the service file in `~/.config/systemd/user/`, it does not work with Wayland since the relevant command is not run with root privileges.

Comment: Why do you Want xdg-desktop-autostart and is WantedBy xdg-desktop-autostart? This might be a problem.